# what is difference between ConnectController and ProviderSignInController in Spring Social

Tags: spring-social

Both ConnectController and ProviderSignInController can create connection with Service Provider so I wonder what is difference between ConnectController and ProviderSignInController

Answer (score 4):

`ConnectController` is just for managing connection with social site.

`ProviderSignInController` has more functions. It works with `ConnectionController` at the beginning. After connection with social site it finds your local user and it loggin that user to your application.